# Google API append CSV file using php

Tags: php, csv, google-api, google-ads-api

Trying to append a CSV file with new data from Google AdWords API every 30 mins. i.e. a new line of data constantly being added to an existing CSV file.

```
  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/report.csv';

  // Run the example.
  DownloadCriteriaReportExample($user, $filePath);
```

This is the current code in the php file, which saves the report as a new CSV file, is there any way to get it to save as a new line of data into a specified file?

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve it?

Comment: I tried using fopen("report.csv", "a") etc. but I can't find the variable that I want to actually write to the file, as it's Google's file that I am just editing to do what I need it to.

Answer (score 2):

if you want simple "append" you can simply do this

```
$variable = xxx; // whatever data you fetched
$file = fopen("example.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $variable);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I can't find the data that has been fetched, as the file is not one I wrote myself, it is one in Google's API examples and so I do not know which variable contains the data I need.

Comment: check all the variables with var_dump() and see which data you want to store

Comment: sorry, could you help further as I am not a programmer, here is the php code, thank you. I want to append a csv file with the data given by the php code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201506/Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReport.php

Comment: well I don't know what the output for DownloadCriteriaReportExample() is .. and what $user is .. so I can't help without at least knowing what is what

Comment: sorry i've edited the comment with a link to the full code: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201506/Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReport.php